# Sending mail from localhost using PHP

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, sendmail

I am trying to send mail from localhost using PHP. I am using the following code to send the mail :-

```
<?php
$to      = 'o****e@gmail.com';
$subject = 'hey You';
$message = 'Can you identify me :P';
$headers = 'From: at*****t@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: at*****t@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

At first, I tried to send the mail to myself(`at*****t@gmail.com`), it worked fine. However, after that, now if I am changing the `$to`, its still sending the mail to same ID(mine) with the previous contents(not the updated one).

Is my request getting cached somehow ? Why every mail is being repeatedly sent to me irrespective of change in both contents and `$to` ?

Comment: Yeah, its the exact code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your php.ini file and change SMTP = localhost to SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com and uncomment sendmail_from and put in your sending gmail address. and set smtp_port = 25
2. Restart localhost

Comment: But I have a SMTP server for sending mail, why should I use my gmail ?

Comment: then use your SMTP address in php.ini and your username and password

Comment: Yeah, I have setted that. Mail is being sent, but not sent to correct person. Also, the contents seem to be cached somehow

Comment: Whenever I execute the code above, mail is being sent, but it is always sent to me irrespective of the id I wish to send. Also, contents of the mail is not changing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18782/discussion-between-prashant-singh-and-elby)